# "... your question on how can I ... " or "your question on how I can ..."

Tags: grammar, word-order, reported-speech

Please take a look at the following sentences and identify the errors.

> "Today I am covering your question on how *can I* hit the shot more cleanly."

Shouldn't the subject "I" proceed the verb "can?" I think it should be written as...

> "Today I am covering your question on how I can hit the shot more cleanly."

Another example,

> I will try to analyze and simplify *what is* the transitive verb and *what is* the intransitive verb.

Again, to my ears it should be...

> "I will try to analyze and simplify what the transitive verb is, and what the intransitive verb is."

Do you guys agree? Please explain further.

Comment: Your ear is good.

Comment: So do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

If you are forming a question, 'subject-verb' inversion works.

> Where is he?

But then, if it's merely information and not a typical question, we don't use that inversion.

> I know where he is.

So, in your case, the latter one fits. :)